# Is there a way I can make a div runat server? So i can turn it into a control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is there a way I can make a div runat server? So i can turn it into a control? In asp.net?

**EDIt:**

IF so how can I tell my code below to make div ID=test runat server?

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
        //div.Style["float"] = "left";

                div.ID = "test";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));
                // this line needs to be represented in sql syntax
                //img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
                img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                div.Controls.Add(img);
                div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;"+"{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                test1.Controls.Add(div);

            }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes

```
<div runat="server"></div>
```

will make it a server side control. You can generate it in the code behind using

```
var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Edit: What you're generating is a server side control, there is no need to add `runat="server"`.

Edit per comment:

```
<div onclick="alert('hello')" runat="server"></div>
```

or

```
var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
myDiv.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('hello');");
```

Comment: I came here looking to use the div with runat=server, but ended up using a span with runat=server so that I wouldn't get a break between the stuff in my container and some text above my control. This helped me get to that solution though, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

You can make a div `runat="server"`, give it an id and the reference it from C# if that's what you're after. However, why not just use an `asp:panel`, they do the same job essentially and the panel renders a div out in most scenarios

Comment: While a asp:panel does create a div in most browsers it isn't guaranteed to do so in all browsers. It depends on the settings inside the browserCaps element in the web.config or machine.config.

Comment: I forgot browserCaps was deprecate after 2.0 and replaced with Browser Definition Files (*.browser). The same warning still applies to them however.

Answer (score 10):

`asp:Panel` is a DIV when it gets rendered

Answer (score -1):

it is definitely not be the most elegant solution, but adding a literal control and build up your div from code will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

ASPX code

```
<div id="alert" runat="server" style="float: left">

</div>
```

C# code

```
alert.InnerHtml= ANY HTML CODE  ;
```