# How to keep DIV shown after post back?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, postback

I have a div with Css Class : display:none and inside the DIV there is asp.net button, when the DIV is slided down and the button inside it is clicked , the DIV is in return slided up,

I want to keep this DIV shown after cilcking on the asp.net button . how ?

Comment: you need to show us some code to understand whats going on

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make the div [runat=server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463266/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-a-div-runat-server-so-i-can-turn-it-into-a-control), and then conditionally set the `display=none` attribute only when `!IsPostBack`.