# add Child DiV inside Parent Div programmatically in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I have this Parent div with class class="scrollContainer" in which I want to add child divs like panel_1 programmatically using asp.net I have searched Google but not getting any where

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
    <div class="panel" id="panel_1">
           <div class="inside">
              <img src="images/p1.jpg" alt="picture" />
               <h2>News Heading</h2><p>A very short excerpt goes here... <a href="#">more link</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `runat="server"` to scrollContainer, then you should be able to access it server-side.

Comment: I have no idea what to do. Can you please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access HTML elements using ASP.NET, you have to add the `runat="server"` attribute to the element. Then, you can access it in server-side code using its ID, which will let you add child elements. See this answer for more information: [Is there a way I can make a div runat server? So i can turn it into a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463266/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-a-div-runat-server-so-i-can-turn-it-into-a-control)

For example:

```
<div id="scrollContainer" runat="server">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using scripts is fine with you, you could write a VBScript inside your ASP.NET page i.e:

```
<%
str = ""
i = 5
for 0 to i 
str = str & "<div>content</div>" & _
 Response.Write(str)
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

your requirement is not clear. But as I understand i think you want to dynamically generate a product list or that kind of thing.. So you use  for do it... i'll put a example code.. refer it..

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="list" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <li style="margin-bottom: 50px;width:100px;list-style:none;">
            <span class="bold">
                <a href='<%# Link.ToProduct(Eval("ItemID").ToString()) %>'>
                    <%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("ItemName").ToString()) %>
                </a>
            </span>

            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="productLink"  
                NavigateUrl='<%# Link.ToProduct(Eval("ItemId").ToString()) %>'
                CssClass='thumb' 
                >
                <img src='<%# Link.ToProductImages(Eval("Image").ToString()) %>' 
                    alt='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("ItemName").ToString()) %>' 
                    class="thumb" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            </asp:HyperLink>
            <p class="bold colr">
                <%# Eval("price", "{0:c}") %>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align:center; height: 50px;">
                <%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("ShortDescription")) %>
                <a href="<%# Link.ToProduct(Eval("ItemId").ToString()) %>">more</a>
            </p>
        </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Comment: My requirement is to add multiple Child divs(random number of divs) like panel_1 into parent div so if I want to add 2 child divs then there wil be 2 child divs with ID panel_1 and Panel_2