# How to get javascript values on code behind in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to get javascript values on code behind in c#.I know i can use hidden field but there is no server control on page for postback.Please tell me how can get vales in code behind.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Get Logged in User Details UserName,Email,Profile Image</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously



    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    // Init the SDK upon load
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APPID', // App ID
            channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                var uid = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture";
                FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                    document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                    document.getElementById('myJSString').value = me.name;

                    alert(document.getElementById('myJSString').value);

                    document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
                    document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;

                    //  document.getElementById('ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPNewT‌​itlesStatus_ChangedRowsIndicesHiddenField').value = uid;
                   // alert('yyy');

                })
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        $("#auth-logoutlink").click(function () { FB.logout(function () { window.location.reload(); }); });
    }





</script>
<h1>
Facebook Login Authentication Example</h1>
<div id="auth-status">
<div id="auth-loggedout">
<div id="Result"  class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true" scope="email,user_checkins">Login</div>
</div>
<div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
Name: <b><span id="auth-displayname"></span></b>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)<br />
Email: <b><span id="Email"></span></b><br />
Profile Image: <img id="profileImg" />

<form runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="myJSString" />

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see there is no server control so how i can get NAME,UID variables in code behind.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463266/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-a-div-runat-server-so-i-can-turn-it-into-a-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would investigate the use of ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, because they allow for script callable stand-alone web services that live in an `.aspx` page, like this:

Page Method in your code-behind file (call it default.aspx for discussion's sake):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string name, string uid)
{
    // Logic here to do what you want with name and uid values (i.e. save to database, call another service, etc.)
}
```

jQuery call to default.aspx's SaveData method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/SaveData",
    data: "{'name':'John', 'uid':'ABC123'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

Notes: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods automatically encode their response to `JSON` so you will not see any `JSON` serialization in the code-behind or any serialization logic at all.

For more information about ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods check out [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: @KAarl i have edit and post my full code now tell me how i can use ajax posting in existing code ..Thanks

Comment: What client-side event do you want to trigger the passing of `name` and `UID` values to the C# code-behind on the server?

Comment: well it depends upon what you are doing with the name and UID on the server, I think you need to explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish with this data in the code-behind.

Comment: i have to save facebook user information in database fields.Right now i am getting information in javascript.you can check.

Comment: I would put the jQuery `.ajax()` call right after this line: document.getElementById('profileImg').src = uid;

Answer (score 7):

You can use a hiddenfield server control assign the values you need to it in javascript and assess it on server side. If you do not want post back then you can use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send values.

*Html*

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField" runat="server"/>
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById('ValueHiddenField').value = "yourValue";
```

*Code  behind*

```
string yourValue = ValueHiddenField.Value;
```

Using **jQuery ajax and web method** to send values to code behind, you can find nice tutorial over [**here**](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: {'yourParam': '123'},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

**Code behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void YourMethod(string yourParam)
{
   //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: You need to do post back, or you can use jQuery ajax call to send values.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to avoid doing a postback, because otherwise I think they would have added a server control to the page, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I cannot use any server side control, i just need to use javascript values on code behind.

Comment: @Adil any suggestion,I need to fix it with the above code,you can see there is no server control..so how i can do it.

Comment: I know thats the way we can do what i am not able to set this in my existing code.can you please once look at my code.

Comment: @Adil i have edited and post full code now please check it and tell me how i can use ajax posting here..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function returnString() {
        var val = 'sampleValue';
        return val;
    }
</script>
```

C# Code to get the return value of the above function:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alertScript", "<script language="javascript">var a=returnString();alert(a);</script>");
```

Or simply as Adil said, can use hidden field and assign value:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hField" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="returnString();"
            Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

**script for assigning value:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function returnString() {
           debugger;
           document.getElementById("hField").value = "sampleValue";
       }
   </script>
```