# How to access a javascript variable in c# code behind without using a hidden field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am storing the data in a variable and passing that to the `txt_val` attribute, stored as `'tooltip'`. I want to access this in my `c#` code, how can I do it?

```
function closediv(val1, txt_val, grp) {
    var data = val1.split("!~!");
    var value1 = data[0];
    $("#" + txt_val).attr('tooltip', value1);            
}
```

I know it can be done using a hidden field, but this value is checked for multiple `textbox` controls, so if I use a hidden field control, I would need to use one hidden field for each textbox, that would result in a lot of repeated code. Is there a better way I can do it? Thank you

Comment: You want to send data from client side back to server side? Why you don't use form posting or calling an ajax to send data to back-end?

Comment: @AfsharMohebbi can you please give an example?

Comment: I mean you finally want to send all data in addition to `txt_val` back to server, right? If yes you can send all of them at once. An example for form posting is using `form` element: `<form method="post" action="test">`

Comment: @AfsharMohebbi yes I want to send all data in addition to `txt_val`, but can you let me know how to do this? I already have `<form method="post" action="test">` in my code

Comment: Yes, I see. Here we need to use hidden fields that you originally wanted to avoid...

Comment: You can use AJAX if you don't want to use hidden field which sent as standard form postback. But it may also requires WebMethod - see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700443).

Comment: Are you sure you have researched this at least a little bit before asking? A quick google search is all it takes

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Object containing values from all the 'textbox` controls and add it to your hidden field by converting it to JSON, like below

```
var extraData = {};

function closediv(val1, txt_val, grp) {
  var data = val1.split("!~!");
  var value1 = data[0];
  $("#" + txt_val).attr('tooltip', value1);
  extraData[txt_val] = value1;
  $('#hiddenFieldId').val(JSON.stringify(extraData));
}
```

then on the controller, you can use JSON.net deserialise this JSON.

```
ExtraData extraDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExtraData>(extraData);
```

Also, if you want to capitalize first letter of the object while serilizing the `extraData`, then you can use solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480570/json-stringify-change-the-case-of-the-key).